# How do I set jquery onclick function to target only specfic table columns or class in an editable table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to make my table editable only for columns with Home_Score and Away_Score names

//edit.js file

```
$(function() {

    //when a td element within tbody is clicked
    $('tbody').on('click','td',function() {
        //call displayform, passing td jQuery element
        displayForm( $(this) );
    });

});
```

//table.php file

```
<?php 

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM predict WHERE Fixture_ID BETWEEN '1' and '10'  ";
                    $results = $dbh->query($sql);
                    $rows = $results->fetchAll();

                    foreach ($rows as $row) {
                        echo '<tr id="'.$row['Fixture_ID'].'">';
                        echo '<td class="Home_Team">'.$row['Home_Team'].'</td><td class="Home_Score">'.$row['Home_Score'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td class="Away_Score">'.$row['Away_Score'].'</td><td class="Away_Team">'.$row['Away_Team'].'</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: Start by using `<form>`  and `<input>` elements in place of the Home and Away text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could do this

```
$(function() {
    //when a td element within tbody is clicked
    $('tbody').on('click', 'td.Home_Score, td.Away_Score', function() {
        //call displayform, passing td jQuery element
        displayForm( $(this) );
    });
});
```

Alternatively, as suggested in another answer, add another class to the cells you want to be able to edit, and use that as the selector.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you be adding rows you can add a class to just the rows you put the vales

```
<?php 

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM predict WHERE Fixture_ID BETWEEN '1' and '10'  ";
                $results = $dbh->query($sql);
                $rows = $results->fetchAll();

                foreach ($rows as $row) {
                    echo '<tr id="'.$row['Fixture_ID'].'">';
                    echo '<td class="Home_Team">'.$row['Home_Team'].'</td><td class="Home_Score editable">'.$row['Home_Score'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td class="Away_Score editable">'.$row['Away_Score'].'</td><td class="Away_Team">'.$row['Away_Team'].'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            ?>
```

then you can update your selector

```
$('tbody').on('click','.editable',function() {
```